# Where are Mac OSX Mountain Lion backgrounds located?

Tags: macos, graphics, background, osx-mountain-lion

Me and my team are doing a project for Mac OSX, but we need to know where all background images in OSX are located. Where are the dock, top bar, launchpad, notification center and spotlight, etc backgrounds stored?

Thanks for your answers guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out:

```
/Library/Desktop Pictures/
/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources/
/System/Library/CoreServices/DefaultDesktop.jpg
```